# Automating the process of graphing a large number of social networks with igraph in R

Tags: r, graph, automation, social-networking

I have a folder containing a large number of adjacency matrices that I want to graph and save as jpegs in a seperate folder. If I want to graph a single network I do the following:

```
library(igraph)
dat <- read.csv("myfile.csv",header=TRUE,row.names=1,check.names=FALSE)
g <- graph.adjacency(m,mode="undirected",weighted=NULL,diag=FALSE)
plot.igraph(g)
```

How would I apply that operation to every file in a directory (e.g. dir1) and save the output graphic as a .jpg in a second directory (e.g. dir2), giving the filename of the original data file to the .jpg?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
setwd(your_directory)
files <- system("echo *.csv", intern=TRUE) # captures output in character vector
files <- strsplit(files, split=" ")[[1]] # only works if there are no spaces in your filenames

for(file in files){
    # read in data
    dat <- read.csv(file,header=TRUE,row.names=1,check.names=FALSE)
    # make into a jpeg filename
    file <- gsub(file, pattern=".csv", replacement=".jpeg")
    jpeg(file)
    g <- graph.adjacency(m,mode="undirected",weighted=NULL,diag=FALSE)
    dev.off() # turns plotting off, needed for the jpeg() function to work well
}
```

cheers. -h

Comment: `files <- list.files(pattern="\\.csv")` might avoid one step.

Comment: Yeah, great answer, nicely explained, but you can avoid using a shell command and just use the functions R provides for globbing/finding files with wildcards.

Comment: Ah, sweet, I didn't know about list.files(). Thanks.

Comment: @HillarySanders thanks for the answer!  However when I enter `files <- system("echo *.csv", intern=TRUE)` I get the following error message: Error in system("echo *.csv", intern = TRUE) : 'echo' not found

Comment: Hm, are you on a mac / unix computer? Echo should be included in the terminal commands. In any case, you can replace my two 'files <-' lines with thelatemail's superior line:
 files <- list.files(pattern="\\.csv")

Comment: @HillarySanders I successfully (as in no error messages :) ran it with the `files <- list.files(pattern="\\.csv")` provided by @thelatemail..and nothing happens.  Am I forgetting something at the end?  I apologize for my ignorance - I am still very new at this.